# Is there a way to split a div based on word wrap?

Tags: html, css

I have a fairly simple div that I have styled with CSS

```
.text { text-transform: capitalize;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        background: #918a8a;
        opacity: 0.6;
        font-size: 2em;
        height: 80px;
        width: 200px;
     }
```

It basically makes a grey box with some white text it in with dimensions 200px by 80px.

What I would like to happen is if the text exceeds the 200px and wraps to the next line, some *transparent* whitespace is added.

So, for instance, if I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="text">Here is some text that I typed</div>
```

I would get this:

[image: Sample Image]

If the background is a different color (in this example, blue) the "whitespace" would be transparent and allow the blue to come through.  The background color is based on what the user picks.  It could also be a picture, so I have no definite control over what it will be.

[image: Sample Image 2]

Assume that the text exceeds the 200px size and that it automatically wraps.  There isn't two separate div tags.  I also have no control over the length of the text - it could be anywhere between 0 and 60 characters.

Comment: As a starting point, you can use the `::first-line` pseudo-selector, but I'm not sure how to do it for every line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient):

```
.text {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    blue, 
    blue 45px,
    transparent 45px,
    transparent 50px
  );
}
```

The first two colors will be your "background" color, and they will cover your text.

The next two colors are `transparent`, and they'll end at the text's `line-height`.

**Snippet:**

```css
body {
  background: #cfc;
}

.text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    blue, 
    blue 45px,
    transparent 45px,
    transparent 50px
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I never would have thought to use "repeating-linear-gradient" in that manner.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with something that sort of works, however the gray background unfortunately won't be the width of the container. You'll need a span within the div as well.

```css
.text-highlight {
  background:#fff;
  width:200px;
}
.text-highlight span {
  font-size:24px;
  color:#000;
  background:#ccc;
  line-height:42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-highlight">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, et, ratione. At facere nisi facilis nulla officiis, suscipit saepe quos cum et sequi nostrum amet atque non quam, consequatur dolor.</span>
  </div>
```

Edit: you can justify the width of the inline elements by specifying it in the parent container...however it might not look as nice.

```css
.text-highlight {
  background:#fff;
  width:200px;
  text-align:justify;
}
.text-highlight span {
  font-size:24px;
  color:#000;
  background:#ccc;
  line-height:42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-highlight">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum, et, ratione. At facere nisi facilis nulla officiis, suscipit saepe quos cum et sequi nostrum amet atque non quam, consequatur dolor.</span>
  </div>
```

Comment: This solution worked really well until the background color changed - which the user has the ability to do.  Then it was a white box with black text on grey backgrounds.  Is there anyway to make the space between the grey backgrounds transparent?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it with a single div element. Please check the below code. This may help you.

```
<div class="text"><span> Here is some text that I typed </span</div>

.text {
        text-transform: capitalize;
        color: #FFFFFF; 
        opacity: 0.6;
        font-size: 2em;
        height: 80px;
        width: 200px; 
     }
.text span{
        background: #918a8a;
        line-height:20px;
}
```